# C# PowerShell - AddScript as multiple statements

Tags: c#, powershell, multiline

I am struggling to find a way to execute a multi-line and multi-statement PowerShell script in C# in such a way, that all the results will be available from the Invoke() method.
It appears that the commands added by **PowerShell.AddScript are always pipelined together**. But I would like them to be read, parsed and **executed as multiple statements with all of the results of the individual statements being written to the output**.

Is that possible?

What I do now:

```
            using PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
            powerShell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted").AddParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser").AddStatement();
            powerShell.AddScript(@"multiple powershell statements 
            on multiple rows, some of them writing to output"); //No intermediate results will be logged or printed as the script is added as a single pipeline
            powerShell.AddScript("$?"); //This is to echo the execution status of the last command into results
            var results = powerShell.Invoke();
```

The results collection contains only one result, and that is the echo of the last $? statement which I then query to find out pass/fail information. I also query Error stream but that is not relevant to the question.

The problem is: **I receive the PowerShell script as a user input** and therefore cannot modify it and add as statements. I was thinking about adding the script line by line, but it will break possible multiline pipelines, codeblocks etc. So to reach the result I want I would need to parse the script myself which sounds quite complex. **Is there any elegant solution to receive all the results from Invoke() and most importantly, add a complex script from user input without it being crushed together as a single pipeline, feeding results of one command to another?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply **use string concatenation to append the `$?` statement** to the statements received, preceded by a `;` (statement separator):

```
powerShell.AddScript(@"multiple powershell statements 
            on multiple rows, some of them writing to output" + ";$?");
```

That way, all statements are submitted as a single script [block] (piece of PowerShell code).

**Successive `.AddScript()` calls aren't cumulative - the last one "wins".**

**Alternatively, append `.AddStatement()` to each `.AddScript()` call**, analogously to how you're already doing for the `.AddCommand()` call that changes the execution policy.

However, it's **more efficient to pass only a *single* piece of PowerShell code, using a single `.AddScript()` call**, as shown above.

---

Finally, the obligatory **security warning**:

> I receive the PowerShell script as a user input

Unless you check and potentially sanitize the input first, only execute it if you trust the source.